# Trying to find an elliptic function such that $\lim_{z \rightarrow \lambda} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = x \;\forall \lambda \in \Lambda$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, complex-numbers, elliptic-functions

Let $\Lambda := \{m + in : m,n ∈ \mathbb{Z}\} \subset \mathbb{C}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. I am trying to find an elliptic function $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \Lambda \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\forall \lambda \in \Lambda $,

$$\lim_{z \rightarrow \lambda} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = x $$

I figured that maybe the Weierstrass elliptic function

$$℘(z,\Lambda) := \frac{1}{z^2} + \sum_{\lambda\in\Lambda\setminus\{0\}}\left(\frac 1 {(z-\lambda)^2} - \frac 1 {\lambda^2}\right)$$

could be used but I've tried to write it down and I can't see how I could conclude.  Could you please help me?

Comment: Is $x$ the real part of $z$? Or is it a constant?

Comment: @user52817: “Let  ... and $x \in \Bbb R$” seems pretty clear to me, $x$ is a given real constant.

Comment: @Martin R, yes it is clear, just seems like a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (non-constant) elliptic function $f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \Lambda \to \mathbb{C}$ has a *pole* at each $\lambda \in \Lambda$, which implies that $f'/f$ has a simple pole at all these points. Therefore
$$
\lim_{z \to \lambda} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = x \in \Bbb R
$$
is not possible if $\lambda \in \Lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

If you meant $f$ is a meromorphic $\Lambda$-periodic function,

Then the equation $x^2=\frac{(\wp_i'(s)^2}{\wp_i(s)^2} = 4\wp_i(s) - g_2(i)/\wp_i(s)$

gives that $f(z)=\wp_i(z+s_k)$ is solution to your problem with $s_k$ one of the two solutions of
$\wp_i(s)=\frac{x^2\pm \sqrt{x^4+16 g_2(i)}}{8}$.

$\wp_i^{-1}(u)$ is given by an elliptic integral.

Comment: It is given that $f$ is  *holomorphic* in $\mathbb{C} \setminus \Lambda$, which means that the poles are necessarily in $\Lambda$, so that $f'/f$ cannot have a finite limit at those points. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Ah maybe, I interpreted it the opposite way, that is $f$ is a meromorphic function on $\Bbb{C}/\Lambda$. Your interpretation makes the question a nonsense whereas mine makes it interesting.

Comment: That's how I interpret “$f : \mathbb{C} \setminus \Lambda \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$” ...